# OpenGL: Interpole keyframes of animated 3d object inside vertex shader

Tags: opengl, animation

Lets say I have `N` vertex buffers that hold the `N` key frames of an animated 3d object, that was created by an application like blender. To smoothly interpolate these frames, I would like to bind two buffers to render the object with a vertex shader like this:

```
in vec4 inPos0;
in vec4 inPos1;

in vec3 inNormal0;
in vec3 inNormal1;

... other attributes...

uniform float time;

void main(){
    vec4 currentPos = mix(inPos0,inPos1,time);
    ... other calculations ...
}
```

To do this, the two buffers must be bound simultaneously, so I'd need to call `glVertexAttribPointer` every time, that a new keyframe should be used. This way buffer `I` can be bound to `inPos0` and buffer `I+1` to `inPos1`.

My question: Is this a good way to interpolate key frames? Or is there any builtin function to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted way is using a skeletal animation.

This means creating bones and putting your vertexes relative to those bones. Then you can transform those bones using only a handful of matrices so that all vertexes can be transformed accordingly.

This technique is called [GPU skinning or skeletal animation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation)